# jquery form plugin prevent default from scrolling up the screen on submission

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-forms-plugin

I've found a number of questions on this but they don't seem to work for me. Finally I thought I'd post it out there in case I'm doing something silly.

The form submits fine however after clicking the save button that causes validation/submit the page scrolls to the top. This is on an input button not a href='#' type issue

```
 <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-orange submit" value="Save">
```

the above submit button kicks off the following

```
$("#submitform").validate({
    // debug: true,
    rules: {
        summary: {
            validateWidthLimits: {max: 49, min: 5}
        },
        description: {
            validateWidthLimits: {max: 49, min: 5}
        },
        start_date: {
            validateDate: true
        },
        end_date: {                     
            validateDate: true
        },
        geocomplete: {
            validateWidthLimits: {max: 500, min: 5}
        }/*,
        // tandcagreed: {
            // validateCheckBoxTicked: {ticked: true, fName: setFeedback2, feedback: $("#mainfbf"), feedbackmsg: "You must agree to our terms and conditions"}
        // }*/
    },
    submitHandler: function(event, validator) {
        submitForm();
        return false;
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        setFeedback2($("#mainfbf"), "All required fields must be filled out", true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I thought the return false would act like prevent default in this case but it's still jumping to the top of the page

Comment: What does `setFeedback2` function do?

Comment: @matewka it may be a custom function

Comment: Indeed. That makes it more probable that it causes the OP's problem.

Comment: setFeedback2 is a custom function that provides feedback to specific div tags. this is unrelated to the problem